# Control history back/fwd of iframe showing external content (cross domain) with javascript in IONIC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, cross-domain

I think the official response will be: "There's no way to do this" but I will give it a try.

This is my scenario: I have an ionicApp that ***must*** show all outbound links inside itself without loosing the "inside the app feeling". It should have the ability to navigate thru the iframe history. [there is a plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) for ionic that uses something similar but it does nothing on desktop and the UI is not good.

I have no control over the iframe contents, so I can't put any scripts in there.

If I try to see the iframe history with:

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.history.back(-1);
```

it throws:

> VM39433:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:8100" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I don't need to do nothing to the iframe elements, *just* control the history (back/forward). Any recommendations on the best way to approach this?